# Stop automation at a certain time

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I'm looking to see if its possible to stop an automation if it goes past 4am?

I have another job which runs at 4:30 and I don't want these jobs to clash.

Comment: Can't you use addition condition with the automation something like 'AND'  time is less than 4AM with other conditions ? It will make whole entry criteria false and the automation would not trigger.

Comment: How do you add additional conditions?

Comment: Why dont you just simply put those two automations in one automation after each other?

Answer (score 1):

This would likely need to be a third automation utilizing Script activities.

What you would do is set this automation to run daily at 4AM with only the script activity.

I would have this script activity utilize the [internal SSJS API capabilities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformAPIFunctions.htm) to [interact with Automation Studio](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm) to do the following actions:

1. Stop the automation if it is running
2. Pause the automation so it does not start again

I would then add a script activity to the end of your 2nd automation and have this script activity restart the first automation so it can run as normal.

[This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225259/how-to-unpause-an-automation-via-api) is a good recently asked question to reference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do this, assuming both automations run on the same days:

Run automation 1 on schedule basis, at the last step of the automation do a file export into a FTP location. The export can be of a dummy DE and as simple as just one row with one field.

Trigger the 2nd Automation off the file drop, this way the 2nd automation only runs if the first has finished.